# Can I use brand names in my short film?

Tags: copyright

Okay, there are two brands I want to use in my short film project:

First one is Ford Focus. The car will be shown explicitly but I can cover the logo with something. Is it okay to film your own car and talk about its model like this : " Yea, its a Focus." ?

And theres another relatively unknown cologne  of one known market . Can I use these without worrying?